Crash in AVPlayerView.setPlaybackControlsViewController
A user of my app, which shows subtitles loaded from a text file on top of a video loaded from another file, reported that it crashes within minutes of launching it. The user confirmed that the crash only happens when they load a video within the app; if they use it without a video, it doesn't crash. The subtitles are shown in a NSTextView added to  AVPlayerView.contentOverlayView.
What could cause such a crash? I'm not able to reproduce it.
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x000000019c50cae8

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [20614]

Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000198a472ec __exceptionPreprocess + 176
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019852e788 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   Foundation                          0x0000000199b2caa0 -[NSKeyValueNestedProperty object:withObservance:didChangeValueForKeyOrKeys:recurse:forwardingValues:] + 664
3   Foundation                          0x0000000199af4e08 -[NSKeyValueUnnestedProperty object:withObservance:didChangeValueForKeyOrKeys:recurse:forwardingValues:] + 196
4   Foundation                          0x0000000199b8bc54 NSKeyValueDidChange + 200
5   Foundation                          0x0000000199acde1c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] + 684
6   Foundation                          0x0000000199af7484 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 64
7   Foundation                          0x0000000199b110e8 _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 284
8   AVKit                               0x00000001bd3ff694 -[AVPlayerControlsViewController setPlayerController:] + 376
9   Foundation                          0x0000000199acddd0 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] + 608
10  Foundation                          0x0000000199af7484 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 64
11  Foundation                          0x0000000199b110e8 _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 284
12  AVKit                               0x00000001bd3c6e68 -[AVPlayerView setPlaybackControlsViewController:] + 88
13  Foundation                          0x0000000199b11074 _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 168
14  AVKit                               0x00000001bd40f4b8 -[AVPlayerView _updatePlaybackControlsViewControllerIfNeeded] + 536
15  AVKit                               0x00000001bd3cc0b4 -[AVPlayerView viewDidMoveToWindow] + 136
16  AppKit                              0x000000019c24456c -[NSView _setWindow:] + 1788
17  AppKit                              0x000000019ccce4a0 __21-[NSView _setWindow:]_block_invoke.146 + 268
18  AppKit                              0x000000019c244564 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 1780
19  AppKit                              0x000000019ccce4a0 __21-[NSView _setWindow:]_block_invoke.146 + 268
20  AppKit                              0x000000019c244564 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 1780
...
35  AppKit                              0x000000019ccce4a0 __21-[NSView _setWindow:]_block_invoke.146 + 268
36  AppKit                              0x000000019c244564 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 1780
37  AppKit                              0x000000019c428ec0 -[NSWindow dealloc] + 684
38  Foundation                          0x000000019a1fa118 _NSKVOPerformWithDeallocatingObservable + 172
39  Foundation                          0x0000000199b17404 NSKVODeallocate + 180
40  Foundation                          0x0000000199b122f0 empty + 88
41  Foundation                          0x0000000199af77fc dealloc + 60
42  Foundation                          0x0000000199af7740 -[NSConcreteMapTable dealloc] + 76
43  AppKit                              0x000000019c936e80 ___NSTouchBarFinderSetNeedsUpdateOnMain_block_invoke_2 + 1388
44  AppKit                              0x000000019c2d4c4c NSDisplayCycleObserverInvoke + 168
45  AppKit                              0x000000019c2d48a8 NSDisplayCycleFlush + 644
46  QuartzCore                          0x00000001a0bc3f64 _ZN2CA11Transaction19run_commit_handlersE18CATransactionPhase + 120
47  QuartzCore                          0x00000001a0bc2d04 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 320
48  AppKit                              0x000000019c3589d0 __62+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]_block_invoke + 272
49  AppKit                              0x000000019cd18208 ___NSRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler_block_invoke + 64
50  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001989d187c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
51  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001989d1768 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 536
52  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001989d0d94 __CFRunLoopRun + 776
53  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001989d0434 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
54  HIToolbox                           0x00000001a317419c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
55  HIToolbox                           0x00000001a3173e2c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 220
...


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   AppKit                                 0x19c50cae8 -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 240
1   AppKit                                 0x19c358b44 __62+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]_block_invoke + 644
2   AppKit                                 0x19cd18208 ___NSRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler_block_invoke + 64
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1989d187c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1989d1768 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 536
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1989d0d94 __CFRunLoopRun + 776
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1989d0434 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   HIToolbox                              0x1a317419c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
8   HIToolbox                              0x1a3173e2c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 220
9   HIToolbox                              0x1a3173d30 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
10  AppKit                                 0x19c22fd68 _DPSNextEvent + 660
11  AppKit                                 0x19ca25808 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 700
12  AppKit                                 0x19c22309c -[NSApplication run] + 476
13  AppKit                                 0x19c1fa2e0 NSApplicationMain + 880
14  Underword                              0x102c099ac 0x102c08000 + 6572
15  dyld                                   0x19856a0e0 start + 2360

